# How to init and insert in Room database using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm new to kotlin and room, after following an official android guide i ended up by setting my entities, my DAO and my Database,

the issue is i can't understand on how can i use the function from dao in my fragment...

So my Database looks like this:

```
@Database(entities = [Articolo::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ArticoliDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val articoliDao: ArticoliDAO
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: ArticoliDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): ArticoliDatabase {
            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE

                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        ArticoliDatabase::class.java,
                        "pdt_database"
                    )
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my fragment i've done the following:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
...
   db = ArticoliDatabase.getInstance(requireContext())
}
```

And in the same fragment in my click function i'm doing the following to insert

```
db.articoliDao.insert(Articolo(barcode, qta))
```

But the app even doesn't build correctly by saying that

```
ArticoliDatabase_Impl does not exist
```

So what is the right way to initialize and use the room database with kotlin?

I just need to simply insert and show the data from the db in a listview that's it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the build.gradle file. Can you please check if your import of room library looks like:

```
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room"
```

Since you are using kotlin, you must use `kapt` for annotation processor dependencies

This is how your room dependencies should look like

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room"
```

Comment: when using kapt i get the following error: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

Comment: Can you post the entire crash log of the build?

Comment: `Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)`

Comment: This is the top exception stack... But, try to post the dao too, i'ma try to run the code here see if it crashes as well :D

Comment: on actually that was an issue with the DAO structure solved it

Answer (score 0):

Create Database class AppDatabase and Dao Interface

**AppDatabase**

```
@Database(
    entities = [User::class, Quote::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getUserDao(): UserDao
    abstract fun getQuoteDao(): QuoteDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var instance: AppDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also {
                instance = it
            }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "MyDatabase.db"
            ).build()
    }
}
```

**Dao Interface Here**

```
@Dao

    interface UserDao{
    
        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        suspend fun upsert(user: User) : Long
    
        @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = $CURRENT_USER_ID")
        fun getuser() : LiveData<User>
    
    }
```

Now in your fragment or activity you can insert and get user data by just craeting an object of dabase class as given below

```
 private val db: AppDatabase

db=AppDatabase(context)

fun saveUser(user: User) = db.getUserDao().upsert(user)

    fun getUser() = db.getUserDao().getuser()
```